# Error: _print_LambertW() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exp'

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying multiply  the following equation with its derivative  using Python, I made the following code

```
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, a,b
from sympy import *
a, b, n, t,N_0,x = symbols('a b n t N_0 x') 
f=-LambertW(-N_0*b**(-a)*log(b)*log(t + 1))/((t + 1)*log(b)*log(t + 1))
f_a=diff(f,a)
d=f*f_a
d
```

When I try to run the code:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
 336             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
 337             if method is not None:
--> 338                 return method()
339             return None
340         else:

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sympy/printing/printer.py in _print(self, expr, **kwargs)
327                 printmethod = '_print_' + cls.__name__
328                 if hasattr(self, printmethod):
--> 329                     return getattr(self, printmethod)(expr, **kwargs)
330             # Unknown object, fall back to the emptyPrinter.
331             return self.emptyPrinter(expr)

TypeError: _print_LambertW() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exp'
```

Comment: When I run this code I get a syntax error at `d=f¨f_a` not the error you describe.

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: Your error is not reproducable

Comment: code has been updated; error is valid

Answer (score 1):

This error is no longer raised in the most recent version of SymPy (or at least the development version).

Comment: I tried with sympy version 1.8, which also doesn't show an error.